# Vertical alignment of tabular to baseline in an itemize environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lists

I have a `tabular` inside an `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[(b)]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            ...
        \end{tabular}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: wrong]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: correct]

I.e. I want to align the top of the table to the present `item` baseline. How?

Comment: I've found conflicting information online, one author proposing that top is default, while [another](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_69.html) suggests "default is alignment on the center of the environment".

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: I think I was wrong: `c` is the default, so a change to `t` is correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) to vertically align the `tabular`s to the `\item`s as the default `[t]`op and `[b]`ottom alignments when including horizontal rules - `\hline`s - influences it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Lorem & Ipsum \tabularnewline
      \hline
      One  &\tabularnewline
      Two  & Wow \tabularnewline
      Three& \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Lorem & Ipsum \tabularnewline
      \hline
      One  &\tabularnewline
      Two  & Wow \tabularnewline
      Three& \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}

  \item
    \adjustbox{valign=b}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Lorem & Ipsum \tabularnewline
      \hline
      One  &\tabularnewline
      Two  & Wow \tabularnewline
      Three& \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Lorem & Ipsum \tabularnewline
      \hline
      One  &\tabularnewline
      Two  & Wow \tabularnewline
      Three& \tabularnewline
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```